# floating value truncation java

Tags: java, floating-point

I want float value of 3 fraction digits after digit. I don't want to round of the value.

For example:

```
float f=2.13275;
```

I want `f` as `2.132` not `2.133`, how can I do that in Java?

Comment: printing a rounded value, or changing the value itself? both responses have answered these questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class.

Comment: Its the best possible thing, I guess.

Comment: Won't this solution round rather than truncate?

Comment: @Asaph, you can use different rounding modes, including RoundingMode.FLOOR or RoundingMode.DOWN.

Answer (score 1):

[Math.floor()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)) will chop off anything after the decimal point without rounding. You can play a trick where you multiply by the appropriate order of magnitude, floor the result and then divide by the same order of magnitude. Like this:

```
double f = 2.13275;
double f2 = Math.floor(f * 1000) / 1000;
```

Note: the Math class deals in doubles, not floats. If you *really* want floats, you can do some casting but there will be some loss of precision. On the other hand, you only want 3 decimal places so you probably won't mind.

Edit: @Jason S points out that negative numbers may have their last decimal place changed. I'm not sure if you want this or if it's even relevant in the context of your code. But if it is, there are a number of ways around it. One is to use [Math.ceil()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)) for the negative number case:

```
double f2 = (f < 0 ? Math.ceil(f * 1000) : Math.floor(f * 1000)) / 1000;
```

Yeah, I know, it's getting a little messy. But it illustrates the point.

Comment: works perfectly for positive numbers. if you want to chop off w/o rounding for negative numbers, you need to use truncation rather than floor, or take the absolute value inside Math.floor() and multiply by the original number's sign afterwards.

Comment: Hi it works for positive values but it not working for nagative float values

Comment: can u tell me plz how to do truncation?

Comment: @sanjana: Good to hear. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it correct by clicking the checkbox beside the answer :)

Comment: Its perfectly correct, but seems work around. I would suggest to use DecimalFormat instead, as 'matt b' suggested. You just cut that part off. Simple isn't it?

Comment: @Vinegar: Won't matt b's solution round rather than truncate?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't (int)(f*1000)/1000.0 work? That seems clearer to me than the other suggestions.

Comment: It's really the same concept as the Math.floor() solution. Anyway, the OP needs it to work for negative numbers and this answer doesn't address that requirement.

Comment: It should do the right thing with negative numbers. That was kind of my point.

Comment: I just checked this, and it does have the right behavior. I was pretty sure that casting to int performed truncation, rather than rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Use DecimalFormat with setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, You can use DecimalFOrmat

`DecimalFormat df= new DecimalFormat("##.###");` //##.### specifies the format that you want

```
String temp=df.format(var_name);
```